# Answered vs Unanswered results inconsistent when searching for tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search, unanswered-questions

When I search for a set of tags (e.g. `jsonschema` and `.net`), [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonschema+.net) and [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/jsonschema+.net) treat the query differently.

**Answered** seems to return questions that have BOTH tags.

**Unanswered** seems to return questions with either tag.

I'd expect to get a list of unanswered questions with BOTH tags.

**Edit**

I linked the queries, but for ease of reading, here are the URLs:

Answered: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonschema+.net`

Unanswered: `https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/jsonschema+.net`

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior of the Unanswered view - tags are ORd rather than ANDed.

To get the behavior you're looking for, you'll have to resort to an advanced search query: [`[jsonschema] [.net] isanswered:0 hasaccepted:0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjsonschema%5D+%5B.net%5D+isanswered%3A0+hasaccepted%3A0)

This matches the behavior of the Unanswered page (no upvoted or accepted answers), but requires questions to match *both* tags.

Comment: But **why** is this the default behavior? It seems counter-intuitive to have one query AND while the other ORs.

Comment: The why is connected to the default filters available for unanswered, @greg... Specifically, "my tags" - this wouldn't be at all useful with an "and"; you'd generally want to see questions in any of your tags, not questions that had *all* of them.

Comment: Then make the default for answered use an OR. I'm not so concerned with which is used so long as they're the same.  It's the difference that's confusing.  Also, it would be hard to implement some kind of UI that lets the user choose.

Comment: Wouldn't* be hard...